# Getting 'Image is missing required "src" property' error with Next.js image

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

This is the error:

> Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass "src" in
> props to the `next/image` component. Received:
> {"width":48,"height":48}

This is my code. I still don't understand at all about this problem.

```js
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import styles from '../styles/roomAvatar.module.css'

const RoomAvatar = ({ id, avatar, name }) => {
    const router = useRouter()

    const changeUrl = () => {
        router.push(`?channel=${id}&name=${name}`)
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.wrapper} onClick={changeUrl}>
            <div className={styles.roomAvatar}>
                <Image src={avatar} className={styles.roomAvatarImage} height={48} width={48} alt={name} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default RoomAvatar
```

Comment: sorry im new, I hope you understand what I typed above

Comment: Hey, please update your post to fix your formatting. and also you did not ask a question, what are you trying to do.. what is the problem you are facing? what are the expected results?

Comment: Make sure you pass a valid string to the `src` prop, and not `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `avatar` props is missing or its return undefined/falsy value

```
const RoomAvatar = ({ id, avatar, name }) => {

console.log({avatar}) // check here or debug here to ensure

const router = useRouter()
const changeUrl = () => {
    router.push(?channel=${id}&name=${name})
}

return (

<Image
    src={avatart ? avatar : 'default-imge.png'} // you can define default image if avatar props is null or empty. If you have defined default value, it will reduce unexpected error/behavior
    className={styles.roomAvatarImage}
    height={48}
    width={48}
    alt={name}
/>
```